# Can I record vkCmdPipelineBarrier multiple times in a command buffer?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have a `vkImage` from the `vkSwapchain`. And my goal is simple, just rendering a triangle into this image. So I created a command buffer and recorded as following orders.

1. `vkBeginCommandBuffer`
2. `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` (from `LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` to `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`)
3. `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`
4. Draw my triangle.
5. `vkCmdEndRenderPass`
6. `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` (from `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` to `PRESENT_SRC`)
7. `vkEndCommandBuffer`

And finally I called `vkQueueSubmit` to get a triangle on the screen. But when the **second** `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` performed, the validation layer says :

> VUID-VkImageMemoryBarrier-oldLayout-01197: For image 0x4 you cannot transition the layout of aspect=1 level=0 layer=0 from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` when the previous known layout is `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR`.

And

> UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout: Submitted command buffer expects image 0x4  (subresource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0) to be in layout `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`--instead, current layout is `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR`.

But I'm sure the image layout will be `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` at that time. I have no ideas why validation layer complain to me.

I've searched API docs and I cannot found any restriction of `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`. They said that this command performs queue ownership transfer(if needed) and layout transition.

Below is my code.

```cpp
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// First layout transition
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
VkImageMemoryBarrier vkGraphicsImageMemoryBarrier
{
    VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER,
    nullptr,
    0,
    VkAccessFlagBits::VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,
    VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,
    this->sSwapchain.vulkanImageList()[nImageIndex],
    VkImageSubresourceRange
    {
        VkImageAspectFlagBits::VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
        0,
        VK_REMAINING_MIP_LEVELS,
        0,
        VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS
    }
};

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    this->sGraphicsCommandBufferList[nImageIndex],
    VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    0,
    0, nullptr,
    0, nullptr,
    1, &vkGraphicsImageMemoryBarrier);

//
//  Draws a triangle.
//

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Second layout transition and ownership transfer
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
VkImageMemoryBarrier vkGraphicsImageMemoryBarrier
{
    VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER,
    nullptr,
    VkAccessFlagBits::VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    0,
    VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
    this->nGraphicsFamily,
    this->nPresentFamily,
    this->sSwapchain.vulkanImageList()[nImageIndex],
    VkImageSubresourceRange
    {
        VkImageAspectFlagBits::VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
        0,
        VK_REMAINING_MIP_LEVELS,
        0,
        VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS
    }
};
VkImageMemoryBarrier vkPresentImageMemoryBarrier
{
    VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER,
    nullptr,
    0,
    0,
    VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
    this->nGraphicsFamily,
    this->nPresentFamily,
    this->sSwapchain.vulkanImageList()[nImageIndex],
    VkImageSubresourceRange
    {
        VkImageAspectFlagBits::VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
        0,
        VK_REMAINING_MIP_LEVELS,
        0,
        VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS
    }
};

//
//  Below call produces the above validation message.
//
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    this->sGraphicsCommandBufferList[nImageIndex],
    VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    0,
    0, nullptr,
    0, nullptr,
    1, &vkGraphicsImageMemoryBarrier);
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    this->sPresentCommandBufferList[nImageIndex],
    VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    0,
    0, nullptr,
    0, nullptr,
    1, &vkPresentImageMemoryBarrier);
```

Despite of the validation error message, I got a triangle rendered. Is this a validation layer bugs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit to how many pipelinebarriers you can record in a command buffer (barring memory limitations)

However there is no need for that particular barrier because the same barrier can be done implicitly by the renderpass. That fact that validation complains that the layout of the image is already present implies that you already set it up that way. Check the finalLayout of the attachment when creating the renderpass.